# Copy all elements from word doc

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, openxml

I'm trying to copy all the elements from a word doc to a new word doc. When I try to get all ChildElements I get the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on this line "For Each element As OpenXmlElement In templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements"

Please help

Code:

```
Dim containerElement = NewDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault()       

Dim clonedElements = New List(Of OpenXmlElement)

For Each element As OpenXmlElement In templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements

         clonedElements.Add(element.Clone())

Next

containerElement.RemoveAllChildren()

containerElement.Append(clonedElements)
```

Comment: In which environment are you working? ASP.NET and VBA are two totally different environments. It looks like ASP.NET. If so, don't you need to declare the `element` variable?

Comment: It is Visual Basic that i run with VBA.net. I should not have added the "A". If I declare a variable and assign the childelements then it stop at the dim statement.

Comment: Once in a while VS will highlight the wrong line when an error is thrown.  Verify that you can access `templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements` without an error being thrown.  Something in that hierarchy might be Null.  (In fact, do you set templateDoc to anything?  You don't show that assignment.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys and girls!

Here is my final working code:

```
                ' Copy XML parts to define document
                NewDocument.AddPart(templatedoc.GetPartById("rId3"), "rId3")
                NewDocument.AddPart(templatedoc.GetPartById("rId2"), "rId2")

                '// Add a main document part. 
                Dim mainPart = NewDocument.AddMainDocumentPart()

                ' // Add a Body               
                mainPart.Document = New Document(New Body())

                'Copy Document XMLParts - must be in specific order
                mainPart.AddPart(templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById("rId8"), "rId8")
                mainPart.AddPart(templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById("rId3"), "rId3")
                mainPart.AddPart(templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById("rId7"), "rId7")
                mainPart.AddPart(templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById("rId2"), "rId2")
                mainPart.AddPart(templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById("rId1"), "rId1")
                mainPart.AddPart(templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById("rId6"), "rId6")
                mainPart.AddPart(templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById("rId5"), "rId5")
                mainPart.AddPart(templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById("rId4"), "rId4")
                mainPart.AddPart(templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById("rId9"), "rId9")


                '// Copy text from template document
                Dim containerElement = NewDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault()
                Dim clonedElements = New List(Of OpenXmlElement)

                Dim elementstocopy = templatedoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements

                For Each element As OpenXmlElement In elementstocopy
                    clonedElements.Add(element.Clone())
                Next

                containerElement.RemoveAllChildren()
                containerElement.Append(clonedElements)

                mainPart.Document.Save()
```